# Client side validations and STI

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, client-side-validation, sti

I am using the client_side_validations gem. How do you suggest getting this to work with STI?

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :year, :presence => true
end

class Car < Vehicle
  validates :cylinders, :presence => true
end

class Motorcycle < Vehicle
  validates :drive_type, :presence => true
end

= form_for @motorcycle, :validate => true do |f|
  = f.text_field :year
  = f.text_field :drive_type
```

Outputs:

```
<input id='motorcylce_year' type='text' \>
<input data-validate='true' id='motorcylce_drive_type' type='text' \>
```

Comment: STI was not the issue...I stand corrected.

Comment: The Github Issue listed below is here: https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/issues/154

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting. This might be a bug. Can you please open an issue on Github?